# KML Lines from fusion table rendering oddly on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm having some issues with a path not rendering properly in an app I'm creating.

If you check this link out: http://jeremyfry.com/test/ simply resize the window so it's wider than tall and the map should show up. You can see the path is a little wonky. The path is correct in my fusion table and if you take the cursor along Riverside Dr you'll see that the path is technically there (the cursor changes to a pointer) but the render is off.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limits to [how complex the kml can be in FusionTables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Geo)

Does your table exceed the 500 feature-per-tile limit?

Comment: Nope. The path is a fairly simple path (maybe 25 points). I've also noticed my zoom bar seems to have some render issues, not sure if that's related.

Comment: if your zoom bar has rendering issues also, then that is probably css related.

Comment: If I look at that area on [a more generic FusionTablesLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=42.318082&lng=-83.043444&zoom=16&type=m&tableid=1226567), the only weirdness I see is the gap in the relay course, is that the path you are displaying?

Comment: Yeah that's the odd part. On the built in map for fusion tables the paths all render fine (it's all the courses I'm having issues with).

Comment: You caught it in the comments. It was a CSS issue. Had to remove `.ui-mobile img {
 max-width: 100%;
}` from jquery mobile and add `#map img{max-width: inherit;}` to my css reset. Whew!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try reducing the line width? Thick lines can result in wonky rendering of lines.

Comment: No luck. Still has the rendering issues with a 1 stroke weight